# Can't connect to my RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created my RDS database with Postgresql using Terraform. But I can't connect to this instance from my computer.

It is set with Publicly accessible: Yes.

I have a security group for it too.

I also have a VPC for it, which have 6 subnets, 2 for each region zone, 1 private and 1 public.

I'll put some prints in https://imgur.com/a/kgIMSno

Comment: The "publicly accessible" flag simply gives the RDS instance a public IP. You still need to set up security groups / routing / etc so that internet ingress works. Your security group looks ok on first look, far too permissive actually, but that's normal for testing. Check your NACLs and routing. FYI you can't ping RDS. Try connecting from an EC2 instance in the same SG / subnet to test it generally works, then try from outside AWS.